# JavaEE 1:1 Unidirectional Relationship

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am confused about how the JPA handles a 1:1 unidirectional relationship when I auto generate my tables from my entity classes vs. how I would make those tables if I was creating the SQL tables myself.

My question concerns how the foreign keys are set up.

Assuming I have a Customer entity and an Address entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Customer{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;

    //setters and getters
}

@Entity
public class Address{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String streetName;

    //setters and getters

}
```

If I generate the sql tables from these two entity classes then the Customer table will have a foreign key column referencing the Address table.

Is there a way to have a OneToOne unidirectional relationship where the JPA sticks the foreign key on the target table(the address table) instead of on the Customer table as it does in my code example, or do I have to make it a bidirectional relationship and show more explicit ownership with the @Mapping annotation to achieve this kind of table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the foreign key appear on the other table for a 1-1 unidirectional relationship you would need to switch the 'owning' side: place customer in Address and remove address from Customer. Then the foreign key for customer would be in the address table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to map your address_id(or something like that) from the Customer entity. For example using below code, you are referencing the Address from the Customer.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID")
private Address address;
```

While deleting any entry from the address table, you must first delete the entry from the Customer table in order to avoid the foreign key violation error. Then you can delete from Address table. JPA doesn't handle this relationship while deleting any row from table.

Comment: I have edited my question to be a little more clear and I apologize for any confusion. My mappings are working as is in my code and the relationship exists, it is simply putting the foreign key on the customer table and I would prefer it to be on the address table, essentially the reverse relationship.